# Ways to stay consistent with theme from jquery-ui

Tags: jquery-ui, styling

I am starting to use some simple widgets from jquery ui together with ui-lightness. I would like to keep my overall layout similar to haw it all looks. Does jquery ui support this in any way? For example I would like to have my radio buttons and checkboxes have similar colors to the ones used in ui-lightness (but I don't want to use radio/checkbox widgets from jquery ui).

Comment: Just edit the css file for jQuery-ui and use it in your project. :)

Comment: The point is, that I don't want to change the theme. I want to apply the theme to other elements on my webpage.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do this by just adding the class names to the widgets - http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Theming/API like for example for buttons you can do this:

```
<button class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" type="submit">Button</button>
```